# Semistable curves of genus $g\geq 2$ form an Artin algebraic stack in the etale topology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, algebraic-stacks

I need the reference to a detailed proof the following fact.

Let $g\geq 2$ be an integer. Let $\mathcal M^{ss}_g: Sch\rightarrow Groupoids$ be the prestack which sends a scheme $T$ to the groupoid of families of semistable curves of genus $g$ over $T$. Then $\mathcal M^{ss}_g$ is a Artin algebraic stack in the Etale topology.

(Also "curves" are schemes, not algebraic spaces.)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "Artin algebraic stack in the Etale topology."  Anyway, I recommend that you look at "Gromov-Witten invariants in algebraic geometry" by Kai Behrend: https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~behrend/gwag.pdf (published in Invent. math.).  Although that Artin stack is not the main point of the article, Behrend does work with that stack in the article.

Comment: Of course my article with Johan de Jong and Xuhua He proves that the stack of all curves is an Artin stack. (This is a folk result; we just wrote down one proof.)

Comment: OK, the last parenthetical sentence of the question suggests that @S.D. wants to only work with schemes. Then in the prestable case it doesn't work. I don't know about the semistable case.

Comment: @Johan I think the sentence is ambiguous.  Perhaps the OP wants the morphism from the universal curve to the Artin stack to be schematic (of course that morphism is schematic).

Comment: Well... that is the thing that is wrong for the prestable curves: there exists a scheme $T$ and a prestable curve $X$ over $T$ such that $X$ is not a scheme. So the morphism from the universal curve to the moduli stack is not representable by schemes (for the prestable case).

Comment: You are correct; there are elliptic curve examples.  I was thinking of the result that every relative curve over a scheme is (Zariski locally on the target) also projective.  So the projection morphism over the Artin stack is, etale locally on the target, a schematic morphism.  As you say, the morphism is not schematic.

Comment: @Jason Starr Thank you for the references. Though I want to learn the proof (if it is correct) of it being an Artin stack in the Etale topology. By emphasising on "Etale topology" I mean to say that the families of semi-stable curves of genus greater than equal to $2$ glue in Etale topology under suitable gluing conditions.  I understand the proof in the case where we also allow algebraic spaces as Johan mentioned.

Comment: @Jason Starr It would be great if you explain the elliptic curve example?

Comment: OK, I think you can make a semistable genus 2 example by gluing 2 elliptic tails to the genus $0$ Example 2.3 in Fulghesu's "The stack of rational curves". It is a bit delicate. Good luck! Also Jason meant "etale local" and not "zariski locally on the target" above.